# Image not showing up on HTML webpage

Tags: html, css

(* I know this question has been asked before on stack, but no other answers have fixed my problem *)

I am having a problem in my HTML/CSS/JS page where an image is not showing up. It's not throwing an error, and everything else still shows up when I run the code.  Any help would be great.

HTML/JS code -

```
<HTML>
    <canvas id = "canvas" width = 480 height = 480>
    <head>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
        <script id = "jqimport" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title> New Web Page </title>


    </head>

    <body onload = "startGame()">
    <img id = "snake" src = "block.png" height = '100' width = '100'>
    <script>

    function startGame() {
    $(document).ready(function() {

    });
    }


    </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

CSS Code -

```
#canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #888888;
    position: relative;

}

#snake {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;

}
```

Comment: I have also tried experimenting in css to see if its hidden behind the canvas, but it is not

Comment: What's that `canvas` tag doing up there?

Comment: `document.ready()` shouldn't be inside another function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus not that it's doing much

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I know. Not the point.

Comment: @jonah_johnson then remove that tag and apply those css rules to `body`

Comment: maybe add `px` or `%` on `width` and `height`? See if that fixes the problem. Have your checked your browser console for any errors?

Comment: The Jquery works within the function

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaScript or JQuery manipulation. And, as long as the CSS doesn't hide it, the only cause would be that the `src` value isn't correct.

Comment: I checked the browser console and the one built into my IED. Nothing is showing up

Comment: Also, since we're giving general advice, remove spaces between attribute names, equal signs and attribute value.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca not that it's doing much ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus touché

Comment: the src value is correct

Comment: @jonah_johnson please, humor me and check if it does work by removing that `canvas` and modifying the first line of your css to read `body {` instead.

Comment: can you just tell me the folders structure about where the image is and where the page you are opening is?

Comment: Inside html tag, only allowed content is one head element and one body element. (If this structure is not followed, browsers usually put extra body start tag before any non head/body content and may ignore second body tag.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html

Comment: @Rob you have closing reasons bingo!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah, I have to rewrite that.

Comment: @Rob, anyway, there is an image tag, right after opening `body`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because the HTML is invalid and unusable as is. Run your HTML through the validator and fix your errors. Your `<canvas>` tag is not closed. This is not a jquery nor javascript question either and you are using obsolete HTML attributes `height`/`width`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where you want the image to show up. However, try the following:

You should put the canvas tag within the body of the html and close it. Play around with the CSS properties of your #snake image. You can set the position absolute if you want it to show up over the canvas or change the left property.

```
<HTML>    
<head>
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
    <script id = "jqimport" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title> New Web Page </title>
</head>

<body onload = "startGame()">
<canvas id = "canvas" width = 480 height = 480></canvas>
<img id = "snake" src = "block.png" height = '100' width = '100'>
<script>...
```

You should be able to see your image then. Again, I am not fully clear as to where you want the image placed.

Comment: He is probably using the canvas for his game. I did not make any assumptions as to what he is trying to draw within it. That was irrelevant to his question @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: That's not valid html, why do you expect it to work? I mean, it may even work, but it's like telling a driver to speed up to 200mph on a driveway. Sure, it will bring you from point A to point B, but it's not how you're supposed to do it!

Comment: His placement of the canvas tag is odd. It should be within the body. That said, I know both ways will work. You can try it yourself and see. I'll edit the answer to reflect the cleaner way of doing it

Comment: His placement of `<canvs>` is not odd. It's flat out wrong! That it "works" for the moment does not matter.

Comment: Right, the answer was edited to address both his img question and the correct placement of the canvas.